# ImportError: cannot import name 'COMError' from '_ctypes' (Speak function)

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, win32com

I have been trying to create a desktop assistant and trying to get it to speak. How can this error be fixed?
I have also tried commands like:
pip3 install pyttsx3
pip3 uninstall pyttsx3
pip3 install pyttsx3=.6
pip3 install pypiwin32

but nothing seemed to work

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/weakref.py", line 136, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
        ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
KeyError: 'sapi5'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/simrankataria/Desktop/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    Assistant= pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyttsx3/engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyttsx3/driver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/sapi5.py", line 1, in <module>
    import comtypes.client  # Importing comtypes.client will make the gen subpackage
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/comtypes/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from _ctypes import COMError
ImportError: cannot import name 'COMError' from '_ctypes' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-311-darwin.so)
```

I am trying to create an AI but I am stuck with this error.
my code:

```
import pyttsx3
Assistant= pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = Assistant.getProperty('voices')
print(voices)
Assistant.setProperty('voices',voices[1].id)

def Speak(audio):
    print("  ")
    Assistant.say(audio)
    print("  ")
    Assistant.runAndWait()

Speak("Blah")
```

Comment: I also tried this but it did not work:                                                                  pip3 uninstall pyttsx3                                                       pip3 install pyttsx3==2.7

pip3 install pypiwin32

Comment: Welcome to SO! [Here's how to ask a proper "Where's the bug / Fix my code" question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/11107541). Can you please read it and apply what you learn to improve your question? You can also read [ask] for further guidance.

Comment: See here: https://superuser.com/questions/609447/how-to-install-the-win32com-python-library, it may help.